# How to inject different service token in the same component?

Tags: angular

I have component **A**, **B**, **C** and service **S**.

**A** and **B** change a value in service **S**.

Component **C** are used twice in different places of the website, so it needs to read different value from service **S**.

In two component **C**, I want one uses token `tokenFromA`, another uses `tokenFromB`.

How to inject different service token in the same component? Thanks

// **Service S**

```
export class Service {
    text:string = '';
}
```

// **Component C**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'c-component',
    providers: [provide("tokenFromA", {useClass: Service})],
    template: `
        <h1>App</h1>
    `
})
export class ComponentC {
    constructor(@Inject('tokenFromA') service:Service) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I mean at some point I want to inject `bar2` not `bar`

Comment: Where and what is "at some point"? At different times of in the same application instance or different for development and deployment, ...?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi, I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I updated my answer. There aren't too many options. I guess you should reconsider your strategy. I guess there are better options, but I don't know any details of your requirements therefore I could be wrong.

Comment: Have you considered passing all your services in the `providers` array?

Comment: @Kutyel thanks, but in this case, I need use different instances, not one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is only supported for tests by `overrideProviders()` of the `TestComponentBuilder`.

It's also possible to request instances directly

```
constructor(private _injector:Injector) {
  var bar = _injector.get('bar');
  var bar2 = _injector.get('bar2');
}
```